# Parent component can get mixins data, but not child components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've encountered an issue when using mixins. I'm not sure if it's some limitations of mixins itself, or a bug in accessing mixins data; having googled my problems, but it seems that none has reported this issue. So let me elaborate here:

I've been building a Vue app, and I've revised my vue components recently. The core component, let's say mainCompo, contains various child components.

The mixins, let's say viewer.js looks like this:

```
export const viewer =  {
    data() {
        return {
            foo:"bar",
            hello:"world"
        }
    },
    methods: {
        testFunc() {
           console.log("test func");
        }
    },
    computed: {
        testComputed(){
           return "123";
        }
    }
```

And the main component mainCompo looks like this: It contains a number of components.
So compoChildA, compoChildB, and compoChildC ... etc are children of mainCompo.

```
import {viewer} from 'mixins/viewer';

export default {
        components:  {
                compoChildA,
                compoChildB,
                compoChildC
        },
        mixins: [viewer],
        data() {
            //...
        }
        mounted() {
            console.log(this.testComputed);
            console.log(this.foo);
            console.log(this.hello);
            console.log(this.testFunc());
        },
        //....
}

<div>
    <compo-child-a></compo-child-a>
    <compo-child-b></compo-child-b>
    <compo-child-c></compo-child-c>
    ...
</div>
```

And let's take a child component compoChildA as an example:

```
import {viewer} from 'mixins/viewer';

export default {
        mixins: [viewer],
        data() {
            //...
        }
    mounted() {
        console.log(this.testComputed);
        console.log(this.foo);
        console.log(this.hello);
        console.log(this.testFunc());
    },
    //....
}

<div>

    ...
</div>
```

Now, all the console logs in the mounted() hook of mainCompo output the data as expected:

```
this.testComputed --> 123
this.foo --> bar
this.hello --> world
this.testFunc() --> test func
```

However, in the case of compoChildA, the results are as follows:

```
this.testComputed --> 123
this.foo --> undefined
this.hello --> undefined
this.testFunc() --> test func
```

The most confusing part is the computed() data can be accessed, but no data() !?

So the question is:
Does it imply that *only* data() from mixins cannot be accessed through child components.

That said, I'm thinking if I'm using mxins correctly.
I've read the official Vue document. The example shows that data can be set in mixins too.
The usage of mixins is to share common things between components, so there should be some way to get the mixins data.

However, store maybe the more appropriate way to get data, so i wonder if I should change to use store instead?

Comment: Mixins are "mixed" in to the component in which they're imported and the data should be treated as such. Like with any other component, any data or methods you wish to share with child components should be passed down using props.

Comment: Yes I do use props in some cases. It’s good but sometimes I have to change the passed data from parent. Vuez store would solve this problem. However, in some cases only one child component will have to change the data. I’ve attempted to use Event bus, it’s an easy implementation but it’s not easy to maintain. That’s why I shift to use mixins.. And now since child components seem to be unable to access mixin data, I think vuez store will be the best and cleanest way..

Answer (score 2):

You cant share data by using mixins.

> Mixins are a flexible way to distribute reusable functionalities for Vue components

You should use Vuex to achieve data sharing through components.

Comment: Ok I got it. At first I read the example of the mixins in the Vue doc and data() is used. Perhaps it’s just some example... and the data is supposed not to be shared across components in the project.

Comment: You can put data() in a mixin, but presumably it would be grabbed only once (on component first render). Following it as a literal rule: use mixin's to share common functionality, but not data.

Answer (score 1):

Mixins cannot be accessed through child components. I have experienced such issue before.
From the docs it states that
"Mixins are a flexible way to distribute reusable functionalities for Vue components. A mixin object can contain any component options. When a component uses a mixin, all options in the mixin will be “mixed” into the component’s own options."

It is used for functionalities not data.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

Comment: Well I just think of an example. An app contains various UI button. All the buttons have similar behavioris, like toggling disability and visibility, and maybe there are some logics to position the buttons.. and also some other methods like hit count...  and mixins is a great way to share these functionalities. However, each button will have different hit counts, different display status.. so mixins are supposed not to be used for data sharing, though I still wonder why only the parent component can update the imported data from mixins.